# moment.js from now is reporting different results in firefox/ie then chrome

Tags: momentjs

We and foolishly assumed a block of momentjs code would work in all browsers.   Right now its correctly working in chrome, but all other browsers its not applying the UTC offset.  How do I make this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/RRr6F/) work consistently in other browsers?  Right now chrome is working, all others are not.

```
 new moment(new Date(date)).fromNow();
 //below shows an example of an exact date. 
 var now = new moment(new Date("2013-09-30T23:33:36.937")).fromNow();
```

In chrome you would see something like "now", all other browsers you would see "in 4 hours"

Comment: What version of firefox?  23.0.1 appears to do the right thing (`a few seconds ago`)

Comment: Have you tried [specifying a timezone](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), such as `Z` or `+0700`?

Comment: I'm using 23.0.1.  The base fiddle was wrong, it was not specifying a time.  @nirk try again.

Comment: @rutter this is coming from a .net mvc api, its supposed to be a valid JSON date.   How are u recommending specifying it ?

Comment: @rutter as a side note. The whole reason we used a framework is so we can let someone else worry about it.  We set all of our dates utc... and expect the library to worry about timezones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to get it to work:

```
var now = moment.utc("2013-10-01T13:15:30.937").fromNow();
```

Note that if you turn it into a  "Date" and call moment.utc

```
var now = moment.utc(new Date("2013-10-01T13:15:30.937")).fromNow();
```

It will not work.  It makes sense now that I think of it.

Comment: There's nothing magical about it.  The `.utc` method is supplying context that you didn't provide in the input string.  And if you bypass moment's parsing functions and rely on the browser, you will get the browser's behavior rather than moment's.

Answer (score 5):

**Original Answer**

Try this:

```
var now = moment(date).fromNow();
```

But rutter is correct that you should specify either a `Z` or an offset like `-07:00`.  From .net, you should make sure you use either a `DateTime` with `.Kind` set to Utc, or use a `DateTimeOffset` field.

**Expanded Answer**

You should understand that when you send a string of `2013-10-01T13:15:30.937`, you are not sending *any* context with it.  There is no way to know from that string alone whether the time is at UTC, or in your server's time zone, or in the browser's time zone.

If you pass it directly to `moment("2013-10-01T13:15:30.937")`, it is going to *assume* the context of the browser's local time zone.

As you discovered, you can tell moment explicitly that this time is in UTC by using the `.utc` function, such as `moment.utc("2013-10-01T13:15:30.937")`.

While this will *work*, there are good reasons not to rely on that alone.  For example, what if you ever use the same server API for another application, or perhaps for third-parties to consume?  Unless you tell them separately that the timestamp is meant to represent UTC, then there is no way to know that.

These strings are in the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) / [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) format.  Part of that specification describes how to indicate that a timestamp is in UTC.  You simply add a `Z` at the end.   If you supply the `Z` then any consumer of this timestamp will know that the time should be interpreted as UTC.  And sure enough, if you pass that into moment directly, such as `moment("2013-10-01T13:15:30.937Z")`, it will give the result you expected.

You said in comments that you were generating these values from ASP.Net Web API.  Run your application in debug mode and set a breakpoint so you can examine the output of your controller.  When you look at the specific `DateTime` property in question, you will see that it has its own `.Kind` property.  It is probably set to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

Since you said specifically that your application uses UTC, then these values should have `DateTimeKind.Utc` instead.  Once that is set, then WebAPI will properly emit the `Z` at the end of the timestamp.

Somewhere in your server-side code, you should do something like this:

```cs
dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

You should do this as early as possible.  For example, in your data access layer when you retrieve the value from the database.  If that's not possible, then at least you should do it in your API Controller so the value gets emitted properly.

See also the MSDN reference for  [`DateTimeKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) and [`DateTime.SpecifyKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind.aspx).

Also - the reason you were getting browser inconsistencies is because you were using the `Date` object's constructor instead of the parsing functions built in to `moment`.  While moment will accept a `Date`, there are several known problems and inconsistencies with how browsers support parsing a `Date` from a string.  Some of those inconsistencies are documented [here](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html).

Comment: your answer is bloated and unrelated to my issue(until the very end).  Our site uses UTC for all times, so there is no need to format it specially we planned on moment taking care of that for us.  My mistake was moment.utc(new Date(bah)) . As soon as I did that the date was assigned a timezone.  When I used the string version, moment took care of what I needed.

Comment: Not sure why you are being so harsh.  I gave you a very simple answer, and you weren't satisfied.  I gave you an expanded answer and you call it bloated.  You don't seem to want to understand *why* it behaved as it did, but were just looking for a quick fix.  However, you are not the only reader of this post.  Others that encounter this question and answer may care more about the details than you do.  A detailed accurate response is not deserving of a downvote just because you don't care to understand what's actually happening.

Comment: The root source of this problem is that you say "our site uses UTC for all times" - however, you are not setting `DateTimeKind.Utc` but rather leaving them as `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  Not understanding the impact of `DateTimeKind` will lead to this problem in particular, and many other problems in general.

Comment: you gave me an answer and it was wrong.  Then edited it to be very long with a lot of content that is loosely related to the problem at hand.  Moment has a way to deal with my situation, and the underlying issue was with using new Date vs the string.

Comment: How was it a wrong answer?  It *does* work.  [Here is a JSFiddle to prove it](http://jsfiddle.net/djSsJ).  You may not choose to see the connection now, but it is *directly* related, not loosely...  With regard to the `.fromNow()` function, you will observe no difference with either approach.  But there *is* a difference that you should be aware of.  If you are going to use `.format` to show the time in the user's time zone, with the approach I recommend it is already taken care of.  With your approach, you will have to first call `.local()`.  I'm just trying to help save you pain later.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 var lastLoginTime = moment(user.lastLoginTime).fromNow();
```